# How to add a line to the file via CMD after specified string?

Tags: string, windows, file, batch-file, cmd

i have a file like this :

```
192.168.123 hostname1
192.168.126 hostname2
192.168.125 hostname3
192.168.124 hostname4
```

And I want to search for a string via CMD ex. `hostname2` and add a line after it so it will look like this:

```
192.168.123 hostname1
192.168.126 hostname2
192.168.128 hostname5
192.168.125 hostname3
192.168.124 hostname4
```

also it all have to be done in orginal file not moved to another

Comment: What have you tried? Why do you need to do it in CMD?

Comment: i tried adding it by echo > file but it adds it and the bottom of the file and yes i have to do it via CMD

Comment: `for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (input.txt) do (` NL `echo %%a %%b` NL `if "%%b" equ "hostname2" echo 192.168.128 hostname5` NL `)`

Comment: Note that AFAIK, batch-file cannot read and write to the same file, at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "string=hostname2"
set "insert=192.168.128 hostname5"

for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%A in (file.txt) do (
    echo %%A %%B
    if /i "%%~B" == "%find%" echo %insert%
) >> file.tmp

move /y file.tmp file.txt
```

The variable `string` is the string to find.
The variable `insert` is the new line to
insert after the line which matches the value of `string`.

The `for` loop delimits each read line by space into 2 tokens.
The 1st token will be the IP address (which seems missing an octate).

If value of `string` is found in the 2nd token at current line being read,
then the `insert` line is inserted.

When done writing to `file.tmp`, the file replaces `file.txt`.